# 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error when setting a range in VBA

Tags: excel-2007, vba, range

I have a function that creates a Pivot Table, but I am getting an error when I try to set a range that will be merged and have a title added to it.

In the below code, `pivot_title_range` is a 'String' variable, and is optional when calling the function. `title_range` is a 'Range' variable. Both lines that set the range (whether or not the users declares `pivot_title_range`) cause the same error.

```
If pivot_title_range = "" Then
    title_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E4")
Else
    title_range = ActiveSheet.Range(pivot_title_range)
End If
```

Here is the error that I am getting -

```
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

If required, here is a Pastebin of the full function - http://pastebin.com/L711jayc. The offending code starts on line 160.

Is anybody able to tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
If pivot_title_range = "" Then
    Set title_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E4")
Else
    set title_range = ActiveSheet.Range(pivot_title_range)
End If
```

Because you defined `title_range as range` - and this is an Object ;)

Comment: If you are like me and looked at this forever without seeing the difference, it is "Set". To make a variable as a range and not an object, `Set var = .Range`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be necessary for variables defined with `As Integer`, I'm learning...Is this correct?  Is `Set` special for setting `Range`s?